# Custom 404 in Snap Web Framework

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework

I am building a website with Snap. How do I specify a custom 404 handler to capture all routes that don't exist?

I would like to redefine the default:

```
No handler accepted "/asdfasdf"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to modify the routing behaviour is by using `wrapSite` :

```
wrapSite (\site -> site <|> writeBS "Use your custom 404 handler" )
```

In the example code, you can add this line in your base Initializer. In Snap Init code, it would be in the `do` from `app` function.

---

Also `""`  will match for any route given. Example:

```
routes = [ ("/login",    with auth handleLoginSubmit)
         , ("/logout",   with auth handleLogout)
         , ("/new_user", with auth handleNewUser)
         , ("/static", serveDirectory "static")
         , ("",        writeBS "This if none of the others" )
         ]
```

You can change the handler for `""` to be your custom 404.

Comment: Thanks for this. It's hard to see this since the default app gives you [("", serveDirectory "/static")] as a default

Comment: This works for some cases, but is is more robust to use the [wrapSite](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/snap-0.13.0.3/docs/Snap-Snaplet.html#v:wrapSite) function to wrap all possible routes, including those possibly defined by other snaplets.  It would look something like this `wrapSite (\site -> site <|> handle404)`.